# How to find out whether a folder require administrative privileges to modify its contents?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5, uac

Given a path to a folder how to find out whether my application needs administrative privileges to create, delete or modify files into this folder?

Qt 5
Windows 8.1

I'd preffer a cross-platform solution. But platform specific will do too.

Comment: Better to ask forgiveness than permission

Comment: Unless you want to introduce a deliberate [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race condition, you ask for permission to create a file by creating a file. You ask for permission to modify a file by modifying a file. You ask for permission to delete a file by deleting a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QFileInfo::isWritable()`:

```
if (fileInfo.isDir() && fileInfo.isWritable()){
....
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `fileInfo.isWritable()` returns `true` no matter what.

Comment: Maybe a bug in Qt?